# create new dataframe from missing values

Tags: r

Consider a vector x:

```
x <- c(0, 5, 10, 25, 30)
```

I would like to create a new vector with "missing values," which means all the values that were "skipped" if I were to have a sequence with intervals of 5.

So for this example, the output shouldbe:

```
xna <- c(15, 20)
```

Additionally, I would have to make a function so that I can do this to any vector x.

```
nats <- function(x){
  lastvalue <- x[length(x)]
  firstvalue <-x[1]
  xseq <- seq(firstvalue, lastvalue, 5)
  for i in xseq {
     # if x is not in x seq put it into a vecotr xna # 
   }
xna
}
```

I really have no idea how to do this. Would really appreciate suggestions or if there is already a function that can do this.

Please help,

Comment: Why is 15 an element of `xna`? It's also an element of `x`, and from what I understand not "skipped". Could you clarify?

Comment: you are correct, I edited the question,. 15 should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in base R (see `?setdiff`)

```
# Your data
x <- c(0, 5, 10, 25, 30)

# Your sequence
y <- seq(0, max(x), by = 5);

# "Skipped" values
s <- setdiff(y, x);
print(s);
[1] 15 20
```

Comment: May I ask a deeper question? Do you have any suggestions on how a beginner like me could efficiently find such a function (such as `setdiff`) on my own? I am often frustrated because I can only ask 90 mins per question, and searching the net and even stack overflow is sometimes overwhelming because there is so much out there, and often it is not exactly what I want, or it is often not presented in a way that I can understand. Would appreciated some feedback.

Comment: No worries @DevangAkotia, I felt very similar when I started learning R. I've got three pieces of advice:
1. Follow (and actually reproduce examples from) publicly available introductory (and intermediate) courses on R.
2. Use the R help. For example, you could find out about `setdiff` when looking up other set operations such as `?intersect` or `?union`.
3. Spend time reading SO R-tagged questions. You'll find that you learn a lot from questions and answers. Dataframe and vector manipulations are at the heart of many R-related questions.

Comment: @DevangAkotia : You might clarify whether are a complete beginner to programming in general or just a beginner with R with solid experience in another computer language. The answer to you "how to find stuff" might differ. In the first case you will need to learn the names of mathematical concepts involved in data manipulation. http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: The first language that I started learning was VBA excel. For some time I was doing most things like data manipulation in VBA, and using R only as the last resort when absolutely needed (such as producing graphs). Now, I find that it would be more efficient to just do everything in R, instead of using 2 languages for a single purpose. I would say that I am a beginner in both languages.

Answer (score 3):

If you need as a function,

```
nats  <- function(x, interval){
   lastvalue <- x[length(x)]
   firstvalue <-x[1]
   xseq <- seq(firstvalue, lastvalue, interval)
   xna <- xseq[!xseq %in% x]
   return(xna)
}

x <- c(0,5,10, 15,25,30)
nats(x, 5)
#[1] 20
x <- c(3, 6,18)
nats(x, 3)
#[1]  9 12 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%in%` operator. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html

```
xna <- xseq[!xseq%in%x]
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited my answer